# HTML Modal not functioning in Django application

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to implement [this codepen](https://codepen.io/rapaccinim/pen/NWjpeVq) into my Django program. I'm not sure why, but I cannot get it to work. I have all of the classes and everything named correctly, but my program does not do anything. I want the user to be able to click on the view button and have an HTML overlay exactly like the one in the codepen, but for some reason nothing is happening when I click on the button. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
{% extends 'suppliesbase.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for donation in donations %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{donation.imageURL}}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{donation.title}}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="openModalBtn" href="#">View</button>
                
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>Free!</strong></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <!--Modal Overlay Content -->
        <div id="modal-overlay">
            <div id="modal">
                <div class="head">
                    <a id="close-modal-button" href="javascript:;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">Modal content</div>
            </div>
       </div>
      <script>
          var openModalButton = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");
          var closeModalButton = document.getElementById("close-modal-button");
         var modalOverlay = document.getElementById("modal-overlay");
         var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

         // function that open modal and display the overlay
         openModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
             modalOverlay.classList.add("modal-overlay-visible");
             modal.classList.add("modal-visible");
         });

         // function that closes the modal and remove the overlay
         closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
             modalOverlay.classList.remove("modal-overlay-visible");
             modal.classList.remove("modal-visible");
         });
     </script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Css is in another file, exactly like the one in the codepen.

Comment: The view button at the top of html

Comment: <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="openModalBtn" href="#">View</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="openModalBtn" href="#">View</button>
```

The ID is incorrect, it should be the following

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="open-modal-button" href="#">View</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that the ID is incorrect, I use your code and still nothing happens

Comment: `var openModalButton = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");` wouldn't work with the ID you have, since it's trying to retrieve the element with ID `open-modal-button` but your code didn't have it, only an element with an ID equal to `openModalBtn`

Comment: Can't believe I made such a small mistake